# File dates using SFTP and FTP connectors in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I need to process files in an order based on the file modify/create date.  I'm using a logic app to process files but cannot get to the date property using the List or the Get from the SFTP Connector or the FTP connector.

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Any access to source code so I can make a tweak or two?

Comment: Thanks Wade - just started a thread and our engineers are looking to ask the owner of this service what could be supported to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The current SFTP and FTP do not return modified date/time.  If you could choose one of the following, do you have a preference?  Not making any promises but investigating best way to resolve this and light up this scenario:

1. Add FileModifiedDateTime property for each file returned
2. Provide a parameter to sort the ListFiles. So, property is still not exposed, but the files are sorted as required by the client so you don't have to check the time of each file to see which is earliest.

Comment: I think that option 1 would be best.  I need the date as part of downstream processing.  In the meantime, I have written a new FTP ApiApp and now fighting what I think is a Passive mode/firewall issue.